# How to print an inner node within a linked list?

Tags: java, linked-list, nodes

I am learning about linked lists. I am able to print a linked list but when I try to create inner nodes I am unable to print any attributes associated with the inner nodes.

I have set up an inner link within my code and it seems to be running but the attributes are not being printed from the program

**Driver Code:**

```
public class Test_HW1
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        LLNode<Directory> node1 = new LLNode<Directory>(new Directory("Users"));
        LLNode<Directory> node2 = new LLNode<Directory>(new Directory("user1"));
        LLNode<Directory> node3 = new LLNode<Directory>(new Directory("user2"));
        LLNode<Directory> node4 = new LLNode<Directory>(new Directory("Program Files"));

        node2.setLink(node3);
        node1.setInnerLink(node2);
        node1.setLink(node4);

        traverse(node1);
    }

    public static void traverse(LLNode<Directory> head)
    {
        while(head != null)
        {
            System.out.println(head.getInfo());
            head = head.getLink();
        }
    }
}
```

**LLNode class:**

```
public class LLNode<T>
{
  protected LLNode<T> link;
  protected T info;
  protected LLNode<T> innerLink;

  public LLNode(T info)
  {
    this.info = info;
    link = null;
    innerLink = null;
  }

  public void setInfo(T info)
  { 
      this.info = info;
  }

  public T getInfo()
  { 
      return info; 
  }

  public void setLink(LLNode<T> link)
  {
      this.link = link;
  }

  public LLNode<T> getLink()
  { 
      return link;
  }

  public void setInnerLink(LLNode<T> link)
  {
      this.innerLink = link;
  }

  public LLNode<T> getInnerLink()
  {
      return innerLink;
  }

}
```

**Directory Class:**

```
public class Directory
{
    private String name;

    public Directory(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        StringBuffer buff = new StringBuffer();
        String retStr = "none yet";

        buff.append(name + "\r\n");

        retStr = buff.toString();
        return retStr;
    }
}
```

My print statement is:

```
Users
Program Files
```

I am expecting it to come out as:

```
Users
   user1
   user2
Program Files
```

Comment: Your code sets inner links but never uses them

Comment: I will try that, thank you

Comment: You're right, I'm assuming that adding an argument for the traverse class would help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like homework, but I see you have already done some 
good work with the classes. What you are trying to do, is accessing the `innerLink` attribute for each traversed node and then traversing it fully, before continuing to the next potential head.

Take a look at your driver code, you are never even calling the corresponding getter. You might want to look into graph-traversal algorithms, especially given the structure your directories will form (is it a special kind of graph maybe?).
Of course, you can (and should) puzzle about this a little yourself - hint: just a single loop won't do it (if you are implementing it non-recursively). Good luck, this is a nice exercise! :)

Comment: Thanks for the response! I will definitely take a look at graph traversal algorithms. You're right, I thought another loop might be necessary to traverse. My goal is to implement it recursively but I was trying to start off with something simple.